# finding the associated value in a list of lists

Tags: python, indexing

I have a list of lists that looks like this:
[['A', 35], ['B', 74], ['C', 21], ['D', 2]]

I want to find the first part of the list based on the second part.

For example, I know I want to get 'C' just by using 21. I know the second part (21) and want to use it to get the first part ('C'). What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Look into using dictionaries if you want to look up values based on another "key"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a dictionary for this:

```
mylist = [['A', 35], ['B', 74], ['C', 21], ['D', 2]]
newdic = dict((y,x) for x,y in mylist)
print(newdic[21])
```

Comment: Thanks! +1 for switching the values and keys in the dict, this is what I needed to be able to look up based on that

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to Jacques's answer:

```
d = {v: k for k, v in [['A', 35], ['B', 74], ['C', 21], ['D', 2]]}
```

It's like an inverse dictionary comprehension, but turns out to be quicker in most cases since you're not using the `dict` function and are rather using the literal syntax `{}`.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to solve this problem is to use a dictioary instead of a list. A dictionary is defined as a pair of key:value and you can run a simple line of code to return the corresponding key of avalue in the dictionary

Comment: Wow, it really was as simple as dict(list_of_lists). Thanks